# How can I save the results of a function in R without returning it?

Tags: r, function, save

I want to save the results of a function without returning it. I know that the variables in the function are local. I tried the followings, they return `NULL`.

```
function1 <- function(directory)
 {
  setwd(directory)
  #some codes
  save(list=ls(.GlobalEnv), file= "result.Rdata")
  # save.image(file= "result.Rdata")
 }

function1("~/Desktop")
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Please, give some details.

Comment: I am applying this function to all files (which are not related) in the directory.

Comment: What do or don't you want to return? NULL is already nothing. You need to give me details.

Answer (score 2):

Please tell more what do you want to achieve.  Do you want to save the result in the file, or in the R workspace?  In the first case

```
function1 <- function(directory) {
  setwd(directory)
  #some codes
  a <- 1
  save(list=ls(), file= "result.Rdata")
}
```

will do the trick. Note: you want to save current environment by *ls()*, not the global environment (unless you assign values there).  But why do you want to save all variables from inside of a function, instead of just the important values?

If you want to save to the workspace, use *assign()*.

Answer (score 1):

What about returning the results `invisible`

```
test <- function(x){
  return(invisible(x^2))
}
test(10) # no display of the result
abc <- test(10)
abc #contains 100
```